# Horisontal scrollbar not working for JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, miglayout

This is my plugin to the application with Miglayout:

[image]

This is MigLayout initialistion code, layout occupies 100% space of main panel:

```
resPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(resPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
mainPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][grow][grow][]", "[][][][grow]"));
mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Class expression"), "wrap");
mainPanel.add(owlDescriptionEditor, "growx,span 3");
mainPanel.add(calcButton, "wrap");
mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Definitions found"), "span 2");
mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Target signature"), "span 2,wrap");
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(resPanel);
mainPanel.add(jsp, "growy, growx, span 2");
jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(deltaList), "growx,growy,span 2");
```

The problem is not working horizontal scrollbar of the left list, which is JPanel with BoxLayout, even though I call setVerticalScrollBarPolicy for it. JPanel is populated dynamically with this loop:

```
static void updateList(JPanel panel, Collection<OWLClassExpression> list) {
    panel.removeAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (OWLClassExpression p : list) {
            String name = ((OWLNamedObject) p).getIRI().getShortForm();
            JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane("text/html", name+"QWQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ");
            jep.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,20));
            jep.setEditable(false);
            jep.setOpaque(false);
            panel.add(jep);
        }
    }
    panel.add( Box.createVerticalStrut(400) );
}
```

I had to add last line to get vertical scrollbar working. If I don't add it, then its also missing, even though it has side effect of extra empty space in the bottom. How can I make scrollbars work properly?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). It'd help if the MCVE / SSCCE used only J2SE layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jep.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,20));
```

Don't hardcode preferred sizes.

Each component will `dynamcially` determine its own preferred size based on the properties of the component (text, font etc.).

The layout manager can then `dynamically` determine the size of the panel based on the preferred size of each component and scrollbars will appear when required.

Also after you are finished adding all the components to the panel you need to use:

```
panel.revalidate();
```

To invoke the layout manager so the new size of the panel can be calculated.